# Strongly typing a Dictionary or NSDictionary to have keys and values as per a protocol

Tags: swift

Here's my protocol:

```swift
@objc public protocol EventListenerOptions {
  @objc optional var capture: Bool { get set }
}
```

I have this method signature:

```swift
func addEventListener(
  _ type: NSString,
  _ callback: ((_ event: UIEvent) -> Void)?,
  _ options: EventListenerOptions?
)
```

How do I invoke it? I've tried using a statically declared dictionary and it's not accepting it. The suggested fix of inserting `as! EventListenerOptions` produces a compiler warning (and crashes at runtime, in any case).

```
view.addEventListener(
  "tap",
  {(event: UIEvent) -> Void in
    print("Got a tap event.")
  },
  ["capture": true] // Error: Argument type '[String : Bool]' does not conform to expected type 'EventListenerOptions'
)
```

Requirements: I want to expose the protocol to Obj-C, so what I'm looking for is some way to get type-safety in Swift while handling an object that is easily constructed in Obj-C (so I can't use structs, to my understanding). I was hoping I could just pass in an NSDictionary casted `as EventListenerOptions`, but it doesn't accept that.

Comment: How about a class? Surely a class is the first thing that came to your mind?

Comment: Why would you think you can pass a `Dictionary` as a custom `protocol`? You need to create a conforming type yourself.

Comment: I suspect OP comes from TypeScript, where the line between dictionaries and types is blurry.

Comment: Sweeper and Dávid, I think that's an unfair attitude - @Alexander is quite right that I come from TypeScript, where this functionality is second nature. I am a bit staggered that Swift doesn't have a feature to just pass in a strictly-typed property bag, as it entails a lot more boilerplate (e.g. you have to manually write an initialiser in order to allow initialising an instance inline) and adds extra symbols to the binary. And that's not to mention the complexity of merging property bags. Thank you Alexander and Bbrk24 for the sympathy!

Comment: @JamieBirch If you do want to use a dictionary, perhaps you could follow the lead of NSAttributedString and use a custom type for the dictionary keys: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1408136-init . NSAttributedString uses a struct for historical reasons but I would probably use an enum.

Comment: @Bbrk24 That doesn't look very useful in this case, sadly - it would be like using the type `Partial<Record<'capture'|'signal', any>>` in TypeScript. It would be fine if each key took a `boolean` value (as I could narrow down `any` to `boolean`), but I want to be able to strongly type property bags whose keys have a mixture of value types (i.e. `{ capture?: boolean; signal?: AbortSignal; }`) without just taking a union of all possible types that the union of all keys support. Your answer does seem to be the Swift way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike in some languages, such as TypeScript, Swift has *nominal* typing rather than *structural* typing. What this means is that even if an object has the shape you want, unless its class explicitly adopts the protocol, you can't pass it in.

```swift
protocol EventListenerOptions {
  var capture: Bool { get set }
}

class AnEventListenerOptionsType: EventListenerOptions {
  var capture: Bool
}

class NotAnEventListenerOptionsType {
  var capture: Bool
}
```

The type of your dictionary `["capture": true]` is not a class which conforms to `EventListenerOptions`: it is the standard library type `Dictionary<String, Bool>`. Not only does this type not adopt the protocol, it doesn't even have the relevant property: you have to access it by `dict["capture"]` rather than `dict.capture`. This is an important difference: the former calls the `subscript(_:)` accessor, while the latter accesses the `capture` property. (If you are coming from TypeScript, as @Alexander suggests, you're probably used to these being equivalent, but in Swift they aren't.)

As far as I'm aware, Swift doesn't have anonymous object literals as in JS, C#, Kotlin etc.

TL;DR: the solution is to create a class which conforms to `EventListenerOptions`.

Answer (score 1):

try to add

```
class Listener: EventListenerOptions { 
 var capture: Bool = true
 }
...
let listener = Listener()
listener.capture = true
view.addEventListener(
  "tap",
  {(event: UIEvent) -> Void in
    print("Got a tap event.")
  },
 listener
)
```